# Implement MKNetworkKit's caching style with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession, mknetworkkit

A newtwork library - MKNetworkKit, that was popular long time ago had an interesting and useful cache style, as docs say:

> MKNetworkKit can automatically cache all your “GET” requests. When you make the same request again, MKNetworkKit calls your completion handler with the cached version of the response (if it’s available) almost immediately. It also makes a call to the remote server again. After the server data is fetched, your completion handler is called again with the new response data.

I wonder if is it possible to implement such behaviour using AFNetworking 2.0 "out of the box". Existing cache policies from NSURLSession doesnt seem to be that I need.All they can whether return cached responce or load data from web with no combinations of both variants.

I'm using subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager to perform network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager is the way to achieve this. Subclass and modify the cache policy.

[AFNETWORKING CACHING](http://www.hpique.com/2014/03/how-to-cache-server-responses-in-ios-apps/)